# Laravel Using The Notification Facade with user email parameter inside it

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send `notification` with a name or email parameter.

**Controller**

```
$subscriber = Subscribe::whereNotNull('verified')->get();
Notification::send($subscriber, new NotifySubscriber($post));
```

**toMail function**

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url = url('/news/' . $this->post->slug);

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->greeting('Dear User')
        ->line('Title : ' . $this->post->title)
        ->action('Read More', $url)
}
```

I want `->greeting('Dear User')` with user name. Like `->greeting('Dear User' . $this->user->name)`

The following didn't work as well:

```
Notification::send($subscriber, new NotifySubscriber($post, $subscriber));
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you use `use Notifiable;` inside your Subscribe model.

then you can access $notifiable it's an instance of the collection you send to the notification class.

```
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url = url('/invoice/'.$this->invoice->id);

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Hello!'. $notifiable->user->name)
                ->line('One of your invoices has been paid!')
                ->action('View Invoice', $url)
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

Check [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait) more details.

Comment: notification work properly if I didn't add `$subscriber` to `NotifySubscriber($post)` since its use notification traits. What i need is how to add user data to notification traits. this can just simply use foreach and send one by one, but that not good i think, so I decide to use `Notification::send($subscriber, new NotifySubscriber($post));` but dont know to add second parameter.

Comment: is there a relation between subscribers and users in your application.
if so you can simply `$notifiable->user->name`